# Is it possible to get the positions of all the stoplights for a given area?

Tags: data, research, united-states, traffic

I would like to know if there is a database of longitude and latitude values that locate all stoplights for a given area in the US like a city or a state? How would one go about obtaining this info?

Looking to gain the locations of stoplights (traffic signals) to do some traffic research.

Comment: Can you say what particular area you are interested in finding such data for? Otherwise it is highly unlikely you will find anything remotely resembling a complete and worldwide dataset for stoplights. The closest thing to that would likely be OpenStreetMap, which has a [`highway=traffic_signals` tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dtraffic_signals), but I don't know how prevalently used it is.

Comment: What geographic area are you looking for?  This is a key detail that I recommend you edit into your Question.

Comment: First define a 'stop light' they mean slightly different things in different countries. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_light (robots, traffic signals, traffic lamps, signal lights)

Comment: @blah238 I will take a look at OpenStreetMap, ideally I would like to be able to get the data points for a particular town or state so that I can research traffic patterns. If one could differentiate between traffic signals and stop signs that would be even more ideal! Just curious if this information is readily available or if i have to petition the city/state for this sort of information.

Comment: @Mapperz Do you know how to query OpenStreetMap to see the traffic lights/streetlights for a specific area?

Comment: @ThePracticalSide Overpass API http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/2E9 example of extracting highway=traffic_signals

Comment: @Mapperz that is EXACTLY what i was looking for! Thank you so much for your help! It does not show me all the stoplights in my area, but at least gives me a start.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, that sort of data will be held, if at all, by local units of government (here in the US anyway) such as a County Highway Dept. or perhaps a State level Dept. Of Transportation. Some of the larger cities or towns may hold this data as well. It is often used as simple inventory data or to keep the signs or stop lights on an upkeep/maintenance schedule. One curious aspect of this typical transportation data is that it is often held as CAD data. It may be available from the local Government entity in your AOI either for a cost or possibly free.